# Does the Browser check conditional headers inside PUSH_PROMISE-frames?

Tags: http-headers, http2, server-push, push-promise

I know that browsers can send `RST_STREAM-frames` to cancel `serverpush`.

Does it make sense to send `Last-Modified` or `Etag` headers inside the `PUSH_PROMISE`? 
Or is the validation of the `to-be-pushed` resources only based on their `URI` (as Simone Bordet answered to the following question two years ago)?

[Does the browser cancel server push when a resource is in cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352282/does-the-browser-cancel-server-push-when-a-resource-is-in-cache)

I couldn't find an exact answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a HTTP/2 server pushes a resource, it generates the `PUSH_PROMISE` frame to send to the client, and at the same time it creates a synthetic request that is processed as if the remote client sent it.

Remember that the `PUSH_PROMISE` frame represent the **request** that the client would make for that resource, not the response.

Typically, the content of the `PUSH_PROMISE` frame headers and the headers of the synthetic request are the same, but - depending on the implementations - it may not be the case.

Headers `Last-Modified` or `ETag` only make sense in responses, so it would not make sense to add them to a `PUSH_PROMISE` frame.

Whether it makes sense to add other *request* headers such as `If-Modified-Since` to the `PUSH_PROMISE` depends on whether the same headers are used for the synthetic request.
If the same headers are used, as it's typically the case, then adding headers such as `If-Modified-Since` has only effects on the server-side processing: the server may generate a `304 Not Modified` when processing the synthetic request.

However, it would be strange for a server to send a `PUSH_PROMISE` for a resource, followed by a `304`. If the server knows that the client already has the resource cached, it may as well skip sending the `PUSH_PROMISE`.

Adding *response* headers such as `Last-Modified` to a `PUSH_PROMISE` frame does not make sense because a `PUSH_PROMISE` represents a request.

Adding conditional *request* headers such as `If-Modified-Since` normally requires the server to have some knowledge about what resources were previously served to the client: it has to know whether a resource has already been served so that sending a `304` to the client for a pushed resource will make the client use the resource already present in its cache.

Comment: Ok, so there's nothing inside the `PUSH_PROMISE` (except the file's URI) that can help the browser to decide if it wants to accept or cancel a push?

Answer (score 1):

After searching deeper i think i found the answer:

The `pushBuilder's` Api says to `.lastModified()`:

> Set the last modified date to be used for conditional pushes.

and to `.etag()`:

> Set the etag to be used for conditional pushes.

I misunderstood those explanations and thought, the specified values are sent to the browser inside the `PUSH_PROMISE` to help it decide whether to accept the pushed file or to cancel the stream (by sending `RST_STREAM`).

In fact, those values seem to tell the server, if it has to push sth. or not. By setting a file's `last-modified-date` as `.lastModified()`, i got the behavior Simone Bordet described in his comment above: a 304 was sent, even if the file didn't exist in my cache.

So now it's fully clear that it doesn't make sense to set these values without knowing exactly what's inside a client's cache.

Something like conditional headers inside a `PUSH_PROMISE` seem not to exist right now: 
I didn't find anything about that in the HTTP2-specs and while reading in chrome's issue-tracker, i found Tom Bergan commenting this on an open (02.01.2017) issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232040#c62):

> ...
>   I think a better way to handle this case is to convert the pushed response to a 304 when the pushed response matches the cached resource. There are two possible implementations:
>
> 1. Don't cancel the push until after receiving the pushed response headers (since the response headers contain ETag and/or Last-Modified). If the pushed resource is already cached, the browser would convert the pushed response to a 304 and cancel the push. However, IMO, this waits too long to cancel the push.
> 2. **Add conditional headers like If-Match to the PUSH_PROMISE so the browser knows exactly which resource is being pushed. This is a good idea but it would need to be spec'd out before we could implement it.**
>      https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2016JulSep/0522.html 
>      ...

So what i expected to be possible (help the browser to check a cached resource's validity by reading out some header-information sent in the `PUSH_PROMISE`) is not possible now, but eventually will be. 
Besides that, it seems that `cache-digest` will be implemented in browsers somewhere in the future, what will be even more effective, because unnecessary pushes can be avoided on the server. Chrome is already working on this, as can be seen here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HhmyzKUPuWcCs8wG_GLSu3mvptygXtO2mBl5xlmEB-4/edit#

Please correct me if i said anything wrong.